# how to use lambda with leftjoin and isnull check

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, left-join, isnull

I am close but no cigar. In SQL I can use an ISNULL in my where clause but I can't seem to get it to pass in linq.

```
var q3 =(
    from Prin in HR
        .Where(Prin => (Prin.JobName == "Pricipal-Elementary")  && 
                        (ASup =>((String.Compare(ASup.UnitName,null) >=0)&&
                        (String.Compare(ASup.UnitName ,"%Learning%"))
                        ))
                )
    //WHERE Prin.JobName = 'Principal-Elementary'
    //AND ISNULL(ASup.UnitName,'') LIKE '%Learning%'
    //ORDER BY SchoolName
    from ASup in HR
        .Where(ASup => ASup.ADAccount == Prin.ChiefADAccount)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from Sch in UnitToSchools
        .Where(Sch => Sch.UnitCode == Prin.UnitCode)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
     SchoolName = Prin.UnitName
    ,SchoolId = Sch.SchoolDetailFCSId
    ,PrincipalID = Prin.ADAccount
    ,LComm = ASup.UnitName
    ,AreaSupId = Prin.ChiefADAccount

    }
);
var xyz = (q3).ToList();

//Below is the correct query in SQL
    SELECT Prin.UnitName AS SchoolName
           , Sch.SchoolDetailFCSId AS SchoolId
         , Prin.ADAccount AS PrincipalID
           , ASup.UnitName AS LComm
         , Prin.ChiefADAccount AS AreaSupID
      FROM IP_F.dbo.HR Prin
      LEFT OUTER JOIN IP_F.dbo.HR ASup
        ON ASup.ADAccount = Prin.ChiefADAccount
      LEFT OUTER JOIN IP_F.dbo.UnitToSchool Sch
        ON Sch.UnitCode = Prin.UnitCode
    WHERE Prin.JobName = 'Principal-Elementary'
       AND ISNULL(ASup.UnitName,'') LIKE '%Learning%'
    ORDER BY SchoolName
```

Any help would be appreciated. Apparently I can't use String.Compare on a lambda. So I am stuck...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your query:

```
 ISNULL(ASup.UnitName,'') LIKE '%Learning%'
```

would be written in LINQ as

```
(ASup.UnitName ?? '').Contains("Learning")
```

Comment: Thanks Molnar. That worked after I abandoned the lambda expressions and added another join for the last column. Can someon +1 this for me? I need 15 more comments on this board.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried something like?

```
(String.IsNullOrEmty(ASup.UnitName) ? string.Empty : ASup.UnitName).Contains("Learning")
```

Comment: I get a NotSupportedException:Method 'Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL [fixed the typo in Emty to Empty]

Comment: Ah, is this using LINQ to SQL? I have only had experience with pure LINQ

Comment: Thanks anyway WraithNath for the quick response